# adding logo in report class

Tags: header-footer

Considering the following

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\headheight{20pt}
\rhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{imagespng/logo}}
\title{My Title}
\author{Author~1, Author~2}
\affil{Institute}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

How is it possible to include the logo `imagespng/logo` in the first page below the date?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\headheight{20pt}
\rhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image}}
\title{My Title}
\author{Author~1, Author~2}
\affil{Institute}
\date{\today \\[1em] \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}}
%% Adjust 1em suitably.

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]